# How can I get Pip to work without "--user"?

Tags: python, macos, flask, terminal, pip

I'm configuring my Mac, and the `pip` command is only working if I add `--user` to it.  I've read up a lot on the issue, and this isn't a shared computer.  Is there a way to configure it so I don't always have to type that (and so I don't have to type `sudo` instead)?

Also, for commands like this:

```
pip install flask --user
```

...the command doesn't run at all.  I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/pip3", line 10, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What version of macOs are you running? You should only have to use sudo for system-wide stuff. It's generally recommended to use virtual environments. What happens when you do `$ virtualenv venv` and then `$ source venv/bin/activate` followed by `(venv) $ pip install flask`?

Comment: it works when I follow your advice.  Is there any way of doing this without creating a virtual env (I understand its not best practice).

Comment: @KingOfTheNorth... If you have root access, you can login to root and run command 'pip install flask'. (Assuming you don't need the virtualenv.)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of an easy way to do that as of today. One way that could work, would be to play with the configuration file and environments variables until it matches your requirements:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file
- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables

Maybe just setting `user` in the global section of your configuration file could be good enough:

```
[global]
user = true
```

I have not tested it, but it might be worth a try.

For info you could read this (fairly long) discussion on the topic:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1668

Also note that a very recent [change in pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/7002) has been made, that could be exactly what you need. No idea if and when it will be released.